# Deploy cosmose db emulator on minikube

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, minikube

Using cosmose db docker preview for linux
I want to deploy the emulator image to minikube

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/linux-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21

How do I create a deploy yaml file from the this command

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -p 10251:10251 -p 10252:10252 -p 10253:10253 -p 10254:10254  -m 3g --cpus=2.0 --name=test-linux-emulator -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true -e AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr -it mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the task using YAML follow below commands -

```
- task: azure-cosmosdb.emulator-public-preview.run-cosmosdbemulatorcontainer.CosmosDbEmulator@2
  displayName: 'Run Azure Cosmos DB Emulator'

- script: yarn test
  displayName: 'Run API tests (Cosmos DB)'
  env:
    HOST: $(CosmosDbEmulator.Endpoint)
    # Hardcoded key for emulator, not a secret
    AUTH_KEY: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
    # The emulator uses a self-signed cert, disable TLS auth errors
    NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: '0'
```

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd#add-the-task-using-yaml